# How are global and local work sizes distributed in this function?

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl

This is from [a sample program](https://github.com/bgaster/opencl-book-samples/tree/master/src/Chapter_14/histogram) for OpenCL programming.
I am confused about how global and local work size are computed.
They are computed based on the image size.

Image size is 1920 x 1080 (w x h).

What I assumed is global_work_size[0] and global_work_size[1] are grids on image.

But now global_work_size is {128, 1088}.

Then local_work_size[0] and local_work_size[1] are grids on  global_work_size.
local_work_size is {128, 32}.

But total groups, num_groups = 34, it is not 128 x 1088.

Max workgroup_size available at device is 4096.

How is the image distributed into such global and local work group sizes?

They are calculated in the following function.

```
    clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo(histogram_rgba_unorm8, device, CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, sizeof(size_t), &workgroup_size, NULL);
    {
        size_t  gsize[2];
        int     w;

        if (workgroup_size <= 256)
        {
            gsize[0] = 16;//workgroup_size is formed into row & col
            gsize[1] = workgroup_size / 16;
        }
        else if (workgroup_size <= 1024)
        {
            gsize[0] = workgroup_size / 16;
            gsize[1] = 16;
        }
        else
        {
            gsize[0] = workgroup_size / 32;
            gsize[1] = 32;
        }

        local_work_size[0] = gsize[0];
        local_work_size[1] = gsize[1];

        w = (image_width + num_pixels_per_work_item - 1) / num_pixels_per_work_item;//to include all pixels, num_pixels_per_work_item is added first
        global_work_size[0] = ((w + gsize[0] - 1) / gsize[0]);//col
        global_work_size[1] = ((image_height + gsize[1] - 1) / gsize[1]);//row

        num_groups = global_work_size[0] * global_work_size[1];    
        global_work_size[0] *= gsize[0];
        global_work_size[1] *= gsize[1];
    }    
    err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, histogram_rgba_unorm8, 2, NULL, global_work_size, local_work_size, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (err)
    {
        printf("clEnqueueNDRangeKernel() failed for histogram_rgba_unorm8 kernel. (%d)\n", err);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any great mystery here. If you follow the calculation, the values do indeed end up as you say. (Not that the group size is particularly efficient in my opinion.)

1. If `workgroup_size` is indeed 4096, `gsize` will end up as `{ 128, 32 }` as it follows the `else` logic. (>1024)
2. `w` is the number of [`num_pixels_per_work_item = 32`](https://github.com/bgaster/opencl-book-samples/blob/3173237ea23ae11462ee3073efeadfa99c2dc5a6/src/Chapter_14/histogram/histogram.cpp#L27) wide columns, or the minimum number of work-items to cover the entire width, which for an image width of 1920 is 60. In other words, we require an absolute minimum of 60 x 1080 work-items to cover the entire image.
3. Next, the number of group columns and rows is calculated and temporarily stored in `global_work_size`. As group width has been set to 128, a `w` of 60 means we end up with 1 column of groups. (This seems a waste of resources, more than half of the 128 work-items in each group will not be doing anything.) The number of group rows is simply `image_height` divided by `gsize[1]` (32) and rounding up. (33.75 -> 34)
4. Total number of groups can now be determined by multiplying out the grid: `num_groups = global_work_size[0] * global_work_size[1]`
5. To get the true total number of work-items in each dimension, each dimension of `global_work_size` is now multiplied by the group size in this dimension. `1, 34` multiplied by `128, 32` yields `128, 1088`.

This actually covers an area of 4096 x 1088 pixels so about 53% of that is wastage. This is mainly because the algorithm for group dimensions favours wide groups, and each work-item works on a 32x1 pixel slice of the image. It would be better to favour tall work groups to reduce the amount of rounding.

For example, if we reverse `gsize[0]` and `gsize[1]`, in this case we'd get a group size of `{ 32, 128 }`, giving us a global work size of `{ 64, 1152 }` and only 12% wastage. It would also be worth checking if always picking the largest possible group size is even a good idea; it quite possibly isn't, but I've not looked into the kernel's computation in detail, let alone run any measurements, to say if that's the case or not.

Comment: I need some discussions.

Comment: Local work group size is defined maximum as 128 x 32. They are assigned in local_work_size[0] = gsize[0]; local_work_size[1] = gsize[1]; The image size is 1920 x 1080 and num_pixels_per_work_item = 32. So number of workitems requirement is 60 for width and 34 for height. Then global_work_size represent how many local_work_size in it. So global_work_size[0] = ((60 + gsize[0] - 1) / gsize[0]) = 1 and global_work_size[1] = ((34 + gsize[1] - 1) / gsize[1]) = 2. But now is global_work_size[0] = 1 and global_work_size[1] = 34. Some more, why they are multiplied with gsize?

Comment: The global dimensions are the total work-**items** in that dimension, **not** the number of groups. OpenCL doesn’t implicitly multiply global by local size. For example if you want 3 groups of size 2 each, you must pass 6 as the global size and 2 as the local size. For OpenCL 1.x global size must be an integer multiple of local size.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Just one thing still confused is that local_work_size = (128,32),  global_work_size[0] = ((60 + gsize[0] - 1) / gsize[0]) = 1 so it should be 128 and global_work_size[1] = ((34 + gsize[1] - 1) / gsize[1]) = 2, it should be 64. But now is global_work_size = (128, 1088). Why need to multiply 32 x 34?

Comment: Each work-item processes a 32x1 pixel tile. So you need a minimum of 1080 work-items in the vertical direction to cover the whole image. 1080 is not an integer multiple of the local size (32) so it must be rounded up to 1088.

Comment: Isn't it I need only 1080(image height)/32 (pixel per one workitem) = 34 workitems for vertical ?

Comment: Let me continue, horizontal needs 1920 / 32 = 60 workitems. Since local_size is 128 x 32, so I need 1 (horizontal) x 2(vertical) workgroups?

Comment: No, each work item is set up to process one row of 32 horizontal pixels as far as I can see.

Comment: You're welcome - like I said I suspect this really isn't an optimal way to divide up the work, but it's definitely consistent and looks like correct use of the OpenCL APIs assuming that is the division the original author of the code had in mind.

Comment: One last question, since I am beginner in this area. Why local work group is not taken 64 x 64. Now is 128 and half of it is wasted.

Comment: I don't know, I didn't write that code. I also have to wonder if the 32x1 pixel choice for each work item is wise. Additionally, going with the maximum possible work group size is possibly also not ideal. In practice, you'd need to benchmark various different combinations across a wide range of hardware before choosing a specific way to split up the work. Note that 64x64 would be just as bad for an image that was e.g. 2050x1000.